# Mule- Mapping key and values to new keys and values

Tags: json, mule, dataweave, mulesoft

I need to extract key and values from json to form different json output

Input Json

```
{"somekey":"xyz",
"properties":{
"key1":"value1",
"key2":"value2"
.....
}
```

Expected Output Json

```
{"somekey":"xyz",
"properties":{
"mainkey1": "value1"
"mainkey2": "value2"
....
}
}
```

I need to add "main" to the existing key and read all the keys. Consider there's n number of key value pairs in properties.
How can this be done dwl script?

I tried to map the objects using payload map and write manually the entire keys. As new key value pairs get added i had to write each keys manually into mapping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [update operator](https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/2.4/dw-operators#update-operator) to update the parent object. Update will keep the existing keys and only update the props object. To concatenate the property keys a mapObject can be used.

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload update {
    case props at .properties -> props mapObject ((value, key) -> {
        ("main" ++ (key as String)): value
    })
}
```